# Accept Unicode Characters along with Underscore via Regex

Tags: php, regex

```
if(preg_match('@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}[^\W_]*$@', $_POST['txt_username_reg'])) 
. . .
```

The above line is used in PHP.

```
'@^([^\W_]*\s){0,3}[^\W_]*$@'
```

The regex allows "English characters + numbers + 3 spaces maximum".

*How can i allow the following:*

- **4 Underscores maximum & Unicode Characters** (Only with No Special Characters Allowed - Discard the request enclosed within brackets).

Comment: You have no sufficiently defined this problem. What the hell is an “international language character” anyways?

Comment: @tchrist International Language Character means Character of an International Language.

Comment: @Mario: Bah! Have you no command of reason, or of English either? The following types of characters exist: Letters, Numbers, Marks, Symbols, Punctuation, Separators, and Others. When you say character, do you mean any or all of those? And what do you mean by language? We only know the names of scripts, like Latin, Greek, Arabic, etc, not the names of languages. And what the hell is international? Used in more than one country? Gosh, that narrows it down a lot. And you call yourself a programmer? Disbelieve!

Comment: @tchrist I don’t think that being a specialist in languages and scripts was needed to be programmer. So me being able to speak 4 languages (three of them fluently) would not count also right?
I am really sorry for my dumb answer though, I did not know that you needed that much details in order to understand something that we all already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\W will match against Standard ASCII English characters, I have done research about this before and could never find a solution until now.

I would normally suggest to match against delimiters (or boundaries) of the words instead and forbid any unwanted characters.

However different approaches are available,
check these links for more information.

1. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
2. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html
3. http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: You're wrong.  You can do a simple implementation of `\w` using nothing more complex than `[\pL\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\pM\p{Pc}]`. Plus if you built your PCRE library right when you linked to PHP at build time, `\w` will already match those; it's a build thing.  Try `(*UCP)` in the regex.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I idiotly keeped the first paragraph without even checking after I found those links.
I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter. So

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:\p{L}*_){1,4}\p{L}*$/u', $_POST['txt_username_reg']))
```

implements your requirements. However, currently these requirements allow `_` as a password, so you might want to rethink those.